# Not able to fetch scope value in back button method in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

On same template ionic is unable to get the value in ion-nav-bar directive.

**Problem** - Whatever the amount I filled in textbox `<input type="text" placeholder="70" ng-model="getamt">` in below mentioned code, I am able to get the same value at `Getting Amt here: {{getamt}}` ie.if I type 56 I am able to get 56 typed like `Getting Amt here: 56` **BUT** I am expecting the same to print at `Not updating Amt {{getamt}}` but in this case I am not getting any value.

I need to send this value to my previous page..so I am trying to do this stuff.

Let me know how to fix this weird issue with ionic.

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack(getamt)">
      <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Not updating Amt {{getamt}}
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-content class="has-subheader" padding-bottom="true">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-30">
        <input type="text" placeholder="70" ng-model="getamt">
      </div>
      <div class="col col-30 item">
        Getting Amt here:  {{getamt}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**EDIT -**

My controller code -

```
.controller('mystate2Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $localstorage, $rootScope, $ionicHistory) {
  console.log("----- mystate2Ctrl -----");

  $scope.myGoBack = function(val){
    console.log(val);
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };

  $rootScope.$on( "$ionicView.leave", function( scopes, states ) {
    if( states.stateName == "app.mystate1" ) {
      console.log("In Ionic View blah blah code here");
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is most likely an issue with isolate scopes in Ionic's directives.  Can you include your controller code?

Comment: @tyler sure..but dont have much code in controller.please find my edit

Comment: @tyler Please find my edit....and let me know if you need any more details

Comment: Try adding `$scope.getamt = 0` to the top of your controller.  Does that fix anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing has to do with nested scopes and in particular with the way you use your "model".

The scope is not the model.

I would suggest you to watch this video from Miško Hevery where he talks about the problem you're having. At some [point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=29m19s) he says something like this:

> Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere.
>   If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.

Anyway, if you want to fix your problem you should define a model in your controller.

The solution is to create one:

```
.controller('mystate2Ctrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state) {

  $scope.mymodel = { getamt: 0 };

});
```

Now you can reference your model in your views using the dot and your view should look something like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="my-app">

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack(mymodel.getamt)">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Not updating Amt {{mymodel.getamt}}
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content class="has-subheader" padding-bottom="true">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-30">
        <input type="text" placeholder="70" ng-model="mymodel.getamt">
      </div>
      <div class="col col-30 item">
        Getting Amt here:  {{mymodel.getamt}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If you want to see how it works you can check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPS2Er7evcZ7BJ1cBRrZ?p=preview).

Probably the best approach is the one John Papa suggests in his Angular [guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

If you read carefully the **controllerAs View Syntax** [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y030) he states why you should go for this approach:

> Why?: It promotes the use of binding to a "dotted" object in the View
>   (e.g. customer.name instead of name), which is more contextual, easier
>   to read, and avoids any reference issues that may occur without
>   "dotting".
>
> Why?: Helps avoid using $parent calls in Views with nested
>   controllers.

This is a second plunker with the [controllerAs](http://plnkr.co/edit/3NJHUElQPdy41IRvgz4p?p=preview) sample.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like because, your `Getting Amt here:  {{getamt}}` and `Not updating Amt {{getamt}}` in two different directives. So make sure they both can access `mystate2Ctrl`.

And try to define the variable in the controller itself.

```
.controller('mystate2Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $localstorage, $rootScope, $ionicHistory) {

  $scope.getamt = 0;
  // your code 
})
```

HTH