# Ionic update Checkbox value

Tags: angularjs, controller, alert, ionic-framework

I'm trying to update the Toggle/Checkbox value back to default/Off when the user selects the cancel option. Currently it sticks to Red/On.

Any suggestions to figuring this out would be great,

**Before**
[image] 
**Alert**
[image] 
**After**
[image]

**Controller**

```
// Default Value
  $scope.turnClearAppData = 'Off';
  // Ionic OK Alert
  $scope.showConfirm = function(val) {
    if ( val == 'On') {
      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Clear App Data',
        template: 'Select OK to Confirm!'
      });
      confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        if(res) {
          // Reset LocalStorage Data
          $localStorage.$reset();
          // Redirect After Reset
          $location.path('/intro/part-one');
        } else {
          // On Cancel Update Value
          $scope.turnClearAppData = 'Off';
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

**HTML**

```
    <li class="item item-toggle noborder">
      Clear App Data {{turnClearAppData}}
       <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="turnClearAppData" ng-true-value="'On'" ng-false-value="'Off'" ng-change="showConfirm(turnClearAppData)">
         <div class="track">
           <div class="handle"></div>
         </div>
       </label>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the scope.
I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30455803/219406) a question few days ago where I have some links to some tutorials where they tell you exactly why you should avoid using scope as a model.

The best solution is to avoid `$scope` to attach your view model.

You can have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OmTKLh?p=preview) where your sample works.

I've used a [ControllerAs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y030) syntax to fix the problem.

It's very easy to implement. In my plunker I've defined the ControllerAs in the state:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController as vm'
});
```

but you can do it in many other ways:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as vm">

</div>
```

in your controller now you create your viewmodel:

```
.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $state, $timeout, $ionicPopup)     {

   var vm = this;

   vm.turnClearAppData = 'Off';

   vm.showConfirm = function(val) {
     if ( val === 'On') {
      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Clear App Data',
        template: 'Select OK to Confirm!'
      });
      confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        if(res) {
          // Reset LocalStorage Data
          // $localStorage.$reset();
          // Redirect After Reset
          // $location.path('/intro/part-one');
          alert('Ok pressed!');
        } else {
          // On Cancel Update Value
          vm.turnClearAppData = 'Off';   
          return vm.turnClearAppData;
        }
      });
    }
  };

});
```

Notice the `var vm = this` as first expression. 
Now all your objects and methods are mapped on the viewmodel (`vm`).

Your HTML now can work with the viewmodel

```
<li class="item item-toggle noborder">
      Clear App Data {{vm.turnClearAppData}}
       <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.turnClearAppData" ng-true-value="'On'" ng-false-value="'Off'" ng-change="vm.showConfirm(vm.turnClearAppData)">
         <div class="track">
           <div class="handle"></div>
         </div>
       </label>
</li>
```

obtaining the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation/answer, it worked perfectly. 

One last thing, would I add VM to the rest of the $scopes within this controller? 

  $scope.$storage = $localStorage; 
  $scope.turnNotifications = 'Off';
  $scope.turnGeolocation = 'Off';
  vm.turnClearAppData = 'Off';

Comment: Glad I've helped. What I suggest is you should never use $scope to store your model; your data. with the controllerAs you can use vm to 'scope' variables and methods. it's much easier to read and it fixes all the scope problems you may find. At the beginning of my answer there's a link to another answer where you can watch a video which explains a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$timeout` in such cases where updating the scope variable value do not update the related changes. Try this.

```
// Default Value
  $scope.turnClearAppData = 'Off';
  // Ionic OK Alert
  $scope.showConfirm = function(val) {
    if ( val == 'On') {
      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Clear App Data',
        template: 'Select OK to Confirm!'
      });
      confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        if(res) {
          // Reset LocalStorage Data
          $localStorage.$reset();
          // Redirect After Reset
          $location.path('/intro/part-one');
        } else {
          // On Cancel Update Value
          $timeout(function () {
             $scope.turnClearAppData = 'Off';
          }, 0);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I've tried the above and the toggle still remains red when clicking cancel, any further suggestions ?

Comment: Try to increase the timeout to 400 ms or more.

Comment: Tried increasing and decreasing the timeout and the checkbox is still set to red when clicking cancel, any further suggestions?

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr?